# How to get user list from replicaset instance?

Tags: mongodb

I have setup a replica set which includes three members. Below is the three instances launch command:

```
501 36057     1   0  4:22pm ??         0:05.02 mongod --replSet replset --dbpath /Users/joey/tmp/replica/replset/rs1/db --logpath /Users/joey/tmp/replica/replset/rs1/mongod.log --port 28017 --logappend --fork
  501 36060     1   0  4:22pm ??         0:04.82 mongod --replSet replset --dbpath /Users/joey/tmp/replica/replset/rs2/db --logpath /Users/joey/tmp/replica/replset/rs2/mongod.log --port 28018 --logappend --fork
  501 36063     1   0  4:22pm ??         0:04.86 mongod --replSet replset --dbpath /Users/joey/tmp/replica/replset/rs3/db --logpath /Users/joey/tmp/replica/replset/rs3/mongod.log --port 28019 --logappend --fork
```

When I connect to one of this member and run `db.getUsers()`, I will get an empty array as below:

```
$ mongo --port 28017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:28017/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0
replset:PRIMARY> db.getUsers()
[ ]
```

I wander how to get user list in replicaset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I connect to one of this member and run db.getUsers(), I will get an empty array

This indicates you haven't set up any users yet. See [Enable Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) in the MongoDB manual.

> Below is the three instances launch command

Your launch commands don't include the `--keyfile` parameter required to enable access control with a replica set. See [Enforce Keyfile Access Control in a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/).

For a full reference of recommended security measures (and links to relevant tutorials), see: [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).